# Publishing data from external API in Meteor

Tags: meteor

For publishing a list of items coming from an external API, I followed the [this tutorial](http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-data-from-an-external-api/): so I've a publication on the server called "items" and a collection with the same name on the client; iron-router is the trait d'union between them. So far so good.

Now I'm stuck in implementing the "item detail" route (e.g. /item/:id). I wrote a server method like this:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    'getItem': function(id) {
        check(id, Match.Integer);
        var self = this;
        var asyncCall = Meteor.wrapAsync(requestToThirdParty); 
        // requestToThirdParty is local function which calls HTTP.get
        var response = asyncCall('GET', id);
        return response.data;
    }    
});
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do, but I'm wondering how to call this method from the following route:

```js
Router.route('/items/:id', {
    name: 'itemDetail',
    data: function() {
        var item = Meteor.call('getItem', this.params.id); // this should be sync
        console.log('item: '+item);
        return item;
    }
});
```

I'm sure that the method on server works fine (I debugged), but the console log in the client always shows "undefined".

What am I missing?
Are there any other approaches?

Comment: Methods are not synchronously styled on the client.

Comment: so is it not possible to call a method on the client and get a result within a route?

Comment: Not unless you use a reactive variable, no.